# my function in prolog doesn't give the expected output

Tags: prolog

So basically , I wanted to do an append function in prolog that adds in the first elemnt of the list as a head if it doesn't exist inside of it otherwise it will return the same list

i wrote this :

```
list_append(F,[],[F]).
list_append(F,[X|XS],[F,X|XS]):- not(member(F,[X|XS])),list_append(F,XS,YS).
```

but it retuns  False instead of a list  when the element exists ... any help ? output :

```
?- list_append(2,[2,2,3],X).
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

[Impure](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/purity) method:

```
append_if_not_member(Elem, LstBeforeAppend, LstAfterAppend) :-
    % Usually perform checks here, e.g. could check that Elem is not a list
    append_if_not_member_(Elem, LstBeforeAppend, LstAfterAppend).

append_if_not_member_(Elem, LstBeforeAppend, LstAfterAppend) :-
    memberchk(Elem, LstBeforeAppend),
    % Found answer - don't try alternative
    !,
    % Assign here, so logic is sound if e.g. LstAfterAppend has a value
    LstAfterAppend = LstBeforeAppend.

% Add Elem to list
append_if_not_member_(Elem, LstBeforeAppend, [Elem|LstBeforeAppend]).
```

Pure method, which loops through the list only once, for performance:

```
append_if_not_member(Elem, Lst, LstAfterAppend) :-
    append_if_not_member_loop_(Lst, Lst, Elem, LstAfterAppend).


% Reached end of list, so Elem is not already present
append_if_not_member_loop_([], Lst, Elem, [Elem|Lst]).

% If head matches Elem, then can stop looking further
append_if_not_member_loop_([Elem|_], Lst, Elem, Lst).

append_if_not_member_loop_([H|T], Lst, Elem, LstAfterAppend) :-
    % Head is different to Elem
    dif(H, Elem),
    % Continue checking the list
    append_if_not_member_loop_(T, Lst, Elem, LstAfterAppend).
```

Comment: `append_if_not_member(1,[1],[1,1])` succeeds

Comment: Corrected the code.

Comment: `append_if_not_member(X,[1],[_,1]), X = 2` fails

Comment: Added pure method.

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling the case where the item **is** already in the list. Also the check for the empty list is probably not needed. So there are just two cases:

- if `X` is a member of `Xs`, the result is `Xs`.
- otherwise... the result is `[X|Xs]`

Try something like this:

```
try_prepend( X , Xs ,    Xs  ) :- member(X,Xs), !.
try_prepend( X , Xs , [X|Xs] ) .
```